# Renaming and reordering chronological Excel files in R

Tags: r, regex, file-rename

I have a set of 67 Excel files that I am trying to merge into a panel dataset in R. The file names are of the form: `qjMMMYYe.xls`, where `MMM` is a three-letter abbreviation for the month, running from `jan` to `nov` in two-month increments, and `YY` is the year, running from `09` to `20`. The first is `qjjan09e.xls` and the last is `qjjan20e.xls`.

I am new to R, and I want to:

a) Read each file into R and name it in a way that can be ordered chronologically, e.g. `qjjan09e.xls` is assigned to `data0901` and `qjjan20e.xls` is assigned to `data2001`

b) Create three new columns in each dataframe: `year` and `month` store the respective date components, and `wave` stores the chronological number of the file (e.g. the first file  `qjjan09e.xls` is assigned `1` and the last file `qjjan20e.xls` is assigned `67`)

c) Stacks the dataframes on top of each other to create a panel dataset

For a), I get the list of filenames through `list.files(pattern="*.xls")` and read them by looping through `read_excel`, but I cannot figure out how to rename the dataframes using regex. I think the `month.abb` function will help me if I can find a way to extract the three-letter abbreviations from the file names. I assume that this part would help me create the year and month columns needed in b), but I am also not sure how to get the wave number from my renamed files. I assume that c) involves `rbind()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involves the `tidyverse` (for some readable data-wrangling), and `data.table` for it's speedy processing of large amounts of data

It's probably not the most elegant way of things, but it will get the job done ;-)

I included comments and in-bewteen-results in the code below

```
library( tidyverse )
library( readxl )
library( data.table )

#get files to read
files.v <- list.files( path = "./temp", pattern = ".*\\.xls$", full.names = TRUE )
# [1] "./temp/qjjan09e.xls" "./temp/qjjan20e.xls"

#build df for lookup operation later on
DF <- data.frame( filename = files.v ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( 
    #use rownumbers to get file identifier
    id = row_number(),
    #extract year and month string from filename, and parse to date
    date_id = paste0( gsub( "^.*([a-z]{3})([0-9]+.*)", "\\1", filename ), 
                      gsub( "[^0-9]", "", filename ) ) %>%
      #parse extracted strings to 'real' date using the corerect locale
      readr::parse_date( format = "%b%y", locale = locale( date_names = "en" ) ) %>%
      #format the date to the desired format
      format( "%y%m" )
    )
#              filename id date_id
# 1 ./temp/qjjan09e.xls  1    0901
# 2 ./temp/qjjan20e.xls  2    2001

#read excel-files to list 
L <- lapply( files.v, readxl::read_excel )
#name list
names(L) <- files.v

# $`./temp/qjjan09e.xls`
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#    col1  col2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     8
# 2     2     9
# 3     3    10
# 4     4    11
# 5     5    12
# 
# $`./temp/qjjan20e.xls`
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#    col1  col2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    11    18
# 2    12    19
# 3    13    20
# 4    14    21
# 5    15    22

#now bind the List together, using it's names as an ID
DT <- data.table::rbindlist( L, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "filename" )
#               filename col1 col2
# 1: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    1    8
# 2: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    2    9
# 3: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    3   10
# 4: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    4   11
# 5: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    5   12
# 6: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   11   18
# 7: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   12   19
# 8: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   13   20
# 9: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   14   21
#10: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   15   22

#now join the relevant info into the coluns needed, using a (fast!!) update join
#  setDT is used on DF to make it a data.table
DT[ data.table::setDT(DF), 
    `:=`( id_col = i.id, date_col = i.date_id ), 
    on = .( filename )]

#               filename col1 col2 id_col date_col
# 1: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    1    8      1     0901
# 2: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    2    9      1     0901
# 3: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    3   10      1     0901
# 4: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    4   11      1     0901
# 5: ./temp/qjjan09e.xls    5   12      1     0901
# 6: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   11   18      2     2001
# 7: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   12   19      2     2001
# 8: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   13   20      2     2001
# 9: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   14   21      2     2001
#10: ./temp/qjjan20e.xls   15   22      2     2001
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you possibly explain to me how the regex lines work? In particular,
`date_id = paste0( gsub( "^.*([a-z]{3})([0-9]+.*)", "\\1", filename ), 
                      gsub( "[^0-9]", "", filename ) ) %>%`

Comment: it is probably easier to see the regexes in action on a site like regex101.com. Let me know if you've still got questions afterward.